# MYSQL table pivot manually to automatic

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to pivotise my columns to get from rows to tables.
It's working like expected with the code I have now, but when my fields get updated I have to manually edit the query in order to update it.
I'm trying to automate the process but I'm not getting it to work. Any ideas?

This is the manual code which works:

```
SELECT 
md.entity_guid AS guid, username, e.time_created, time_updated, e.enabled, banned,e.last_action, last_login,
MAX(IF(msn.string = 'question1', msv.string, NULL)) AS question1
FROM exp_metadata md
JOIN exp_metastrings msn ON md.name_id = msn.id
JOIN exp_metastrings msv ON md.value_id = msv.id
JOIN exp_users_entity u ON u.guid = md.entity_guid
JOIN exp_entities e ON e.guid = md.entity_guid
GROUP BY
guid
```

And this is the query I'm trying to do to automate it:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
md.entity_guid AS guid, username, e.time_created, time_updated, e.enabled, banned, e.last_action, last_login,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(msn.string = ''',
      msn.string,
      ''', msv.string, NULL)) AS ',
      msn.string
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM exp_metadata md
JOIN exp_metastrings msn ON md.name_id = msn.id
JOIN exp_metastrings msv ON md.value_id = msv.id
JOIN exp_users_entity u ON u.guid = md.entity_guid
JOIN exp_entities e ON e.guid = md.entity_guid
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT e.guid, ', @sql, ' FROM exp_entities e GROUP BY e.guid');
```

I get an error in `phpmyadmin` about the last line.
When I delete the last line to see if it does anything, I get:

> `#1222` - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks a lot, Dries

Comment: See [#1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946709/1222-the-used-select-statements-have-a-different-number-of-columns)